# Why was season 4 episode 4 of My Hero Academia delayed?

Tags: my-hero-academia

Season 4 episode 4 of My Hero Academia isn’t out, and people on the internet are saying it's been delayed, but no one seems to know the reason why.

Why was season 4 episode 4 of My Hero Academia delayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The planned broadcast on 2 November 2019 for season 4 episode 4 of *My Hero Academia*  was delayed due to the [2019 Rugby World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_Rugby_World_Cup).**

2 November 2019 is the final match of the 2019 Rugby World Cup which is hosted in Japan and broadcasted nation-wide.

[The official announcement](https://twitter.com/heroaca_anime/status/1190451999910711301) on the Twitter:

> [お知らせ]
>   今日11月2日(土)のTVアニメ『僕のヒーローアカデミア』第4期の放送は、ラグビーワールドカップ決勝放送のためお休みです。次回4期4話(通算第67話)「抗う運命」は11月9日(土)放送になります。あと1週間、お待ちください!